# SimpleDateFormat().format() changed the timestamp value?

Tags: java, groovy

I am converting a timestamp from "1999-02-18 11:30:00.0" to "1999-02-18 11:30:00".  Well, simple enough. So I use following:

```
newForm = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss').format(oldForm)
println oldForm
println newForm
```

However, the print out shows the value of the timestamp is changed.

```
oldForm 1999-02-18 11:30:00.0
newForm 1999-30-18 11:30:00
```

This really drive me crazy.  Is this a bug or what? Anyother way to do it? I really don't want to do string trimming

Comment: Assuming `oldForm` is a Date, you can just do `oldForm.format( 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss' )` with Groovy

Answer (score 7):

You should use (capital) `MM` for month; `mm` is minutes, which is 30 here.

[Date Format Symbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: D'oh ...  what a mistake!  Thank you so much for your quick reply!

Comment: @YangLu If this was the answer to your question, why not mark it as so?

Answer (score 1):

`mm` is not the Month.  You should do this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 1):

mm is minutes.  MM is month.  all fixed.

Comment: Once you have received a correct answer, it is desirable to 'accept' it, and give it an upvote if you have found it helpful. It's the way SO works.  I think the earliest correct answer should get the accept, just to be fair.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'mm' instead of 'MM'

mm is for minutes

MM is for month

Also check this page for more details

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

It will help you whenever you will be dealing with     SimpleDateFormat